# Export Sheet API pdf version issue

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-workspace, google-developers-console

Description
While exporting the pdf using google sheets API then it's downloading as the 1.4 version so it's cutting my few characters which are last in the sentence line. and while we are printing or downloading the pdf manually then it's downloading the pdf in 1.7 version so help me out in this for the download the file in 1.7 version.

Code

```
export_url = f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheet_id}/export?format=pdf"
export_options = {
    "format": "pdf",
    "portrait": True,  # Set to False for landscape orientation
    "fitw": True,  # Adjust the sheet to fit on a page
    "sheetnames": False,  # Hide sheet names
    "horizontal_alignment": "CENTER",  # Set sheet in the center horizontally
    "vertical_alignment": "MIDDLE",  # Set sheet in the center vertically
    "scale": 4,  # 1 = 100% scaling
    "size": "A4",  # Page size options
}
response = requests.get(export_url, params=export_options)

with open(pdf_path, "wb") as f:
    f.write(response.content)`
```

Output
Output pdf version is 1.4

[image]
[image]

[Click here to see the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AO0G.png)
Like this getting the cropped text

[click here to see the excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg9ao.png)
in Gsheet it's proper

Want to export the pdf to the 1.7 version or the text should not be cut

Comment: Please check the updated issue with the attached images

Comment: Width solution is not working

Comment: In order to test your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: Sure @Tanaike let me share

You can utilize this sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1feRdasxxJt4VFUCBogbPEHnrUtft4p4zWpobNmHC90o/edit#gid=1144840266

If we exported using python script or the above code then it's cutting the characters. by manually it's exporting perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for providing your sample Spreadsheet. When I saw your spreadsheet, I noticed that you are using the font of "MS Pゴシック". I guessed that the reason for your current issue might be due to the font. As a simple modification, please change the font from "MS Pゴシック" to "Arial" and test it again. When I tested this modification, I confirmed that it might be close to your expected result. How about this? I posted it as a comment because I'm not sure whether this is your expected result. I apologize for this.

Comment: I fount that it's working for the print functionality and working fine but not working fine for the download file

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand the relationship between `I fount that it's working for the print functionality and working fine but not working fine for the download file` and my comment.

Comment: I checked in detail more @Tanaike and found 1 thing if we export the excel sheet using the download option and using ctrl + P both are exporting differently. Please check that and the font thing also there but we can not fix this because it's behavior is not fix

Comment: no worries @Tanaike, That means the if you download the file using download and save pdf using CTRL+P both will be different

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the details of the relationship between `That means the if you download the file using download and save pdf using CTRL+P both will be different` and my comment?

Comment: Yes @Tanaike, You are correct.

Comment: @Tanaike And about your past comment regarding the font change I tested but it's not working. Test this scenario - change the column width or remove few any columns it will not work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor skill. About `And about your past comment regarding the font change I tested but it's not working.`, unfortunately, when I tested it using your provided Spreadsheet, I confirmed that it might be close to your expected result. I deeply apologize for this again. In order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating it?

Comment: Yes @Tanaike, If you add or remove the columns or change the column width then you will find the issue and also try to take the sentence from the excel sheet url. And if possible lets connect via mail so we can communicate fast and easily akshatshah19575@gmail.com.